# Help Updating XML file using MSBuild Extensions 4 with namespaces

Tags: msbuild-4.0, msbuildextensionpack

I'm having some trouble getting MSBuild extensions 4.0 to update an XML file once a namespace is involved.

When I have a simple XML file with no namespace then fine, but once i attempt to update an xml file that has a namespace set, then nothing happens .. notice there is no error tho.

Here are the simple ones that work fine

```
    <Project>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <ApplicationVersion>5.1.500.16</ApplicationVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <ApplicationVersion>old</ApplicationVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

and project file

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <TPath>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
            <AssemblyVersion>5.1.500.18</AssemblyVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Import Project="$(TPath)"/>
        <Target Name="Default">
            <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="RemoveElement"  "  File="c:\build\test.csproj"  XPath="/Project/PropertyGroup[1]/ApplicationVersion" />
        </Target>
    </Project>
```

Wheras these dont do anything !

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project xmlns="http://mynamespace">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <ApplicationVersion>5.1.500.16</ApplicationVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <ApplicationVersion>old</ApplicationVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

and

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <TPath>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
            <AssemblyVersion>5.1.500.18</AssemblyVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Import Project="$(TPath)"/>
        <ItemGroup>
            <Namespaces Include="Mynamespace">
                <Prefix>me</Prefix>
                <Uri>"http://mynamespace"</Uri>
            </Namespaces>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Target Name="Default">
            <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="RemoveElement"  Namespaces="@(Namespaces)"  File="c:\build\test.csproj"  XPath="//me:Project/PropertyGroup[1]/ApplicationVersion" />
        </Target>
    </Project>
```

So what's the deal ? what am i missing ? Is it the formatting of the XPath in the second instance ? I've tried all kinds of variations.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    <Target Name="Default">
        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="RemoveElement"  Namespaces="@(Namespaces)"  File="c:\build\test.csproj"  XPath="//me:Project/me:PropertyGroup[1]/me:ApplicationVersion" />
    </Target>
```

(namespace prefix before each xpath element)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the advice given in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6071179/806690), remove the quotes from the `Uri` metadata in the `Namespace` item.

Note that according to the note for the prefix parameter in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx), specifing the empty string for the `Prefix` metadata will never work.